# TileView Image Column Not Show image (Devexpress)

Tags: c#, image, devexpress, gridcontrol

i have gridControl on my form that converted to Tileview Layout and i want to show my data from database to tileview, my problem is that my image not show and just show its bytes.how i can fix this? i used repository.Edit.Picturebox but problem exist.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this- [Grid Control - (converted to TileView) - How to show an image column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T200734/grid-control-converted-to-tileview-how-to-show-an-image-column)

> Columns are automatically created when you assign a data source to a
>   grid. Populate tile items based on these columns manually by using the
>   Grid Designer. Your image will be shown properly if your column type
>   is Image or Byte[].

Approach which I have used is that I have created a separate column my datasource which contain byte array as shown in below code snippet:

```
templateRow[TableColumnName.ImagePath] = finalPath;
templateRow[TableColumnName.Image] = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ByteImageConverter.ToByteArray(
                                    System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(finalPath), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

There are several different ways to display icons in cells. Please review the [How to put an image in a grid cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A900.aspx) article, which demonstrates several possible approaches related to this task.

References:
[Tile View not loading image from column containing Image Path](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T231475/tile-view-not-loading-image-from-column-containing-image-path)
[byte array column to image display](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q200983/byte-array-column-to-image-display)